# Delphi Indy Post Encoding and PHP

Tags: php, delphi, post, character-encoding, indy

The string returned from php script is encoded.

I have a problem with an http post in delphi 2007 and Indy 10.6 towards a php script.
The php script contains:
header ("Content-Type: application / json; charset = UTF-8");
The Delphi part is this:

```
  data: = TStringList.Create;

  dati.Values ​​['id']: = '6';
  dati.Values ​​['name']: = 'àèìòù';

  lParams: = TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  cont: = 0;
  try
    try
      url: = 'someurl';
      while cont <= data.Count-1 do
      begin
        lParams.AddFormField (data.Names [cont], data.Values ​​[data.Names [cont]]);
        Inc (cont);
      end;
      Response: = IdHTTP1.Post (url, lParams);
    except
      on E: Exception do
      Response: = E.ClassName + ':' + E.Message;
    end;
  finally
    lParams.Free;
    IdHTTP1.Disconnect;
  end;
  Result: = Response;
```

Response contains what should be saved in the mysql database whose varchar field is declared utf8-general-i
both in the field and in the php echo, however, they return:
= E0 = E8 = EC = F2 = F9

I tried to encode with UTF8Encode (dati.Values ​​[data.Names [cont]]), I tried to pass the UTF-8 charset to AddFormField but the string àèìòù is never returned.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have shown looks like MIME's `quoted-printable` encoding, where non-ASCII/reserved byte octets are encoded in `=HH` hex format. `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` does encode text fields in quoted-printable format by default. `=E0=E8=EC=F2=F9` is the QP-encoded form of the byte sequence `$E0 $E8 $EC $F2 $F9`, which is the text `'àèìòù'` encoded in the Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) charset.

PHP does not support the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header in `multipart/form-data` submissions ([see this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48219)), so it does not automatically decode the QP encoding for you.  So, you will have to either:

- decode the QP encoding manually in your PHP script code.
- disable `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` from applying QP encoding, by setting the `TIdFormDataField.ContentTransfer` property to `'8bit'` instead of the default `'quoted-printable'` (note that [RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578) deprecates the use of the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header in `multipart/form-data` submissions over HTTP, but `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` has not been updated to account for that yet <sup>1</sup>).

  <sup>1: Note - the `TIdFormDataField.ContentTransfer` property *can* be set to a blank string, which will disable the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header from being sent, but it will also send the text as 7-bit US-ASCII, per [RFC 2045 Section 6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.1), so don't use this option if you need to send text that contains non-ASCII characters.</sup>

Also, be aware that Delphi 2007 is not a Unicode enabled version of Delphi (ie, `String` = `AnsiString`), which is why your text is being posted in Latin-1.  In pre-Unicode versions, `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` transmits `AnsiString` data as-is, so you are responsible for pre-encoding the posted `AnsiString`s in the desired byte encoding, such as UTF-8.

Try this instead:

```
url := 'someurl';

try
  data := TStringList.Create;
  try
    data.Values ​​['id']: = '6';
    data.Values ​​['name'] := UTF8Encode('àèìòù'); // <-- omit UTF8Encode() in D2009+...

    lParams := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      for cont := 0 to data.Count-1 do
      begin
        lParams.AddFormField(data.Names[cont], data.ValueFromIndex[cont], 'utf-8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
      end;

      try
        Response := IdHTTP1.Post(url, lParams);
      finally
        IdHTTP1.Disconnect;
      end;
    finally
      lParams.Free;
    end;
  finally
    data.Free;
  end;
except
  on E: Exception do
    Response := E.ClassName + ':' + E.Message;
end;

Result := Response;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now in the db the data is saved correctly. I had tried UTF8Encode on the offending string but it didn't work. At this point I believe that the only substantial difference is in the addition of the .ContentTransfer: = '8bit'; that I completely omitted.
But now the server returns me (rightly) àèìòù formatted in Unicode "\u00e0\u00e8\u00ec\u00f2\u00f9"
I accept the answer anyway as it solves the server side problem.
While for reception I tried to use UTF8Decode but without success.

Comment: Update:
I tried to get back the single unicode string with echo $ val; from PHP and use:
Response: = IdHTTP1.Post (url, lParams, IndyTextEncoding_8Bit);
where Response is an AnsiString of D 2007 and is now displayed correctly.
Ufff I'm almost done.