# TIdHTTP POST long strings issue on Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy10

I need to send a multipart/form-data to a webservice via TIdHTTP POST and get a JSON as response. I'm using de code bellow:

```
procedure TForm1.btnExecutarClick(Sender: TObject);var
  Data: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;  
  resposta: TMemoryStream;
  vMensag : String;
begin

  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  try
    SSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2, sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv23, sslvSSLv3];
    HTTP.IOHandler := SSL;
    HTTP.HTTPOptions := HTTP.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoWantProtocolErrorContent, hoForceEncodeParams];

    Data := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    resposta := TMemoryStream.Create;

    vMensag:= 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eget ' +
              'ligula eu lectus lobortis condimentum. Aliquam nonummy auctor massa. ' +
              'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada ' +
              'fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla at risus. Quisque purus magna, auctor et, '+
              'sagittis ac, posuere eu, lectus. Nam mattis, felis ut adipiscing.';


    Data.AddFormField('mensagem', vMensag);

    try          
      HTTP.Request.Clear;
      HTTP.Request.Accept := 'multipart/form-data';
      HTTP.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
      HTTP.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';

      HTTP.Response.CharSet:= 'utf-8';
      HTTP.Response.ContentType:= 'application/json';
              
      HTTP.HandleRedirects  := True;
      HTTP.Post('http://localhost/teste/server.php', Data, resposta);

      Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
      try
        resposta.Position := 0;
        ReadStringsAsCharset(resposta, Memo1.Lines, HTTP.Response.Charset);
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Response Code: %d', [HTTP.ResponseCode]));
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Response Text: %s', [HTTP.ResponseText]));
        Memo1.Lines.Add(FStrList.Text);
      finally
        Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
      end;
    finally
    end;
  finally 
    resposta.Free;
    Data.Free;
  end;
```

The response I get on Memo1 for the string I send on vMensag is:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eget
> li=\r\ngula eu lectus lobortis condimentum. Aliquam nonummy auctor
> massa. Pel=\r\nlentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
> malesuada fame=\r\ns ac turpis egestas. Nulla at risus. Quisque purus
> magna, auctor et, s=\r\nagittis ac, posuere eu, lectus. Nam mattis,
> felis ut adipiscing.

These "=\r\n" line breakers wasn't supposed to occur, am I wrong?

Trying a POST using Insomnia, the string is transferred correctly.

The echo Server I'm using to test is very simple:

```
<?php
  $usermens = "";

  if (isset($_POST['mensagem'])) 
  { 
      $usermens= $_POST['mensagem'];
  }
  
  
    $dados = array('mensagem' => $usermens);

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    
    echo json_encode($dados);          
?>
```

Is there any configuration on TIdHTTP I'm missing or something like that?

Comment: You need to fix your `try..finally` blocks.

Comment: Art least it is regular - `=\r\n`  is being added every 70 characters.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Brian yes, the string is getting this breakers at each 70 characters

Comment: @RondinelleBrazolino by default, the text is being encoded using MIME's Quoted-Printable scheme when sent to the server,  but the PHP script is not decoding it before sending it back. See the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145621/) I just linked to (just ignore the parts about ANSI, since it is an old question, but the main solution about handling the QP encoding still applies)

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the quote. I'll read the post you linked